# Shell script as default browser

Tags: macos

Let's say I have an executable file called `my_link_opener`, how do I set it as the default browser?

I have tried the following already, without success:

**Wrapping it as an .app**
I tried using [Appify](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099) and then setting the generated .app as my default browser in Safari.
However, because OS X expects programs to only have one "instance" that opens many links in its lifetime, this doesn't work out.
Instead of passing the URL on the command-line, it sends a `-psn_xxxxx` argument.

**Wrapping it with Automator**
Turns out, [if you add it as a workflow in Automator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664194/174466) you can make it take opened files as arguments.
However, that only works for *files and folders*.
As far I see, there is no way to make URLs valid input for the Automator workflow.

So, I'm out of luck. Is there any other kind of wrapping magic I could do?

Comment: Why not having another script wrapped in Appify that manages the `-psn_xxxxx` option and that launches a new instance of your `my_link_opener` for each option?

Comment: I suppose that's an option. Has nobody done that already? Sounds like an awful lot to learn.

Comment: Not AFAIK. But I will check later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find any already option (but still, some may exist) so I ended up writing one.
Basically what it does is telling the system that the app *IS* a browser, eventually set itself as default browser (see `#define SET_AS_DEFAULT_BROWSER`) and finally manages the url when it receives the right event by sending the url to a script called `my_link_opener` located in the app's bundle (that is, inside the .app directory). The bash command called is:

`nohup /path/to/my_link_opener "_an_url_" >& /dev/null &`

```
#import "ZFTAppDelegate.h"

NSString *runCommand(NSString *commandToRun)
{
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

    NSArray *arguments = @[@"-c" ,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commandToRun]];
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *output;
    output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return output;
}

#define SET_AS_DEFAULT_BROWSER

@implementation ZFTAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSAppleEventManager *em = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
    [em setEventHandler:self
            andSelector:@selector(getUrl:withReplyEvent:)
          forEventClass:kInternetEventClass
             andEventID:kAEGetURL];
    [em setEventHandler:self
            andSelector:@selector(getUrl:withReplyEvent:)
          forEventClass:'WWW!'
             andEventID:'OURL'];


#ifdef SET_AS_DEFAULT_BROWSER
    CFStringRef bundleID = (__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme(CFSTR("http"), bundleID);
    LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme(CFSTR("https"), bundleID);
#endif


}

- (void)getUrl:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    NSString *url = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
    NSString* scriptPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my_link_opener"];
    runCommand([NSString stringWithFormat:@"nohup %@ \"%@\" >& /dev/null &", scriptPath, url]);
}

@end
```

Remember that in the app's info.plist you should have this (needed to inform the OS about the capability of your app to handle http/s urls):

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>https</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Secure http URL</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>http</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>http URL</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Could you provide some points on how to compile this, though?

Comment: Yes, I have XCode installed already. I'm just not sure how the project is supposed to look like.

Comment: Just create a new mac application project, the code above goes in the appdelegate.m, the xml in the info.plist. If you can't make it work i'll update it later on github

Comment: Sorry, I really can't figure this out. It builds and everything, but nothing seems to happen when I open URLs with it. I'd appreciate anything you might suggest that'd fix this.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by changing "nohup %@ \"%@\" >& /dev/null &" into the simpler "%@ \"%@\"". Maybe there was an issue with the > part? Anyway, thanks for your help.