# Open With Application: How to detect filename in go

Tags: macos, go

I have created a go application on my mac that reads/writes from files *.myext. The executable was packed into an a Bundle called "MyApp".

I can start MyApp and then read/write *.myext files, that works.

My question is: how to detect the filename if I am opening e.g. test.myext by Open With > MyApp (usually right mouse button)?

I have tried to read the file name from os.Args, but the file name is not in there.

Is there a way?

Thank you for your help!

Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a program started via "Open With" does not receive the name of the file it has been invoked on but rather has to obtain it using "Apple events" as described [in the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664124/macosx-open-file-with-an-application-where-does-it-go-to).

I am thereby afraid currently the only way to solve the problem would be to use [`cgo`](http://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo); may be along [these lines](https://gist.github.com/kavu/6740536).

Comment: I would also recommend to subscribe to the [`go-nuts` mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts/) and post your question there, linking to this your SO question.  That's because your problem IMO suggests a more extensive solution than you have supposedly envisioned.

Comment: Thank you for these hints! It looks as the solution is a bit more complicated than I was hoping ;-).